# scala to java conversion for user-defined function (UDF) in sparksql

Tags: java, apache-spark

```
spark.sqlContext.udf.register('dataSource', (data: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef, ofType : String) => {

    var flag = ''
    try{
    val array: Seq[String] = data.flatten(x => Seq(x.toString()))
    array.foreach(s => if(s.contains(ofType)) { flag = ofType })
    }
    catch {
    println("Exception :" + x.getMessage)
    flag = ''
    }
    flag;

})
```

Comment: please help me how to covert this code from scala to Java

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to convert this Scala code into Java code. In Spark you can register a UDF in any of the languages and also make use of it in either Java or Scala as long as it is used in the same SparkSession or Context.

Comment: no i have converting the scala application into java. So I am writing the code into JAva